# Proving $-\cos\alpha = \sin(\alpha-90^\circ)$ from $\sin (\alpha-\beta) = \sin\alpha\cdot\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cdot\sin\beta$

Tags: trigonometry

$$-\cos\alpha = \sin(\alpha-90^\circ)$$ but
$$\sin (\alpha-\beta) = \sin\alpha\cdot\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cdot\sin\beta$$

How does this work out?

$$\begin{align}
\sin\alpha\cdot\cos\beta &=\phantom{-}0\\
\cos\alpha\cdot\sin(-90^\circ)&=-1
\end{align}$$
so I get 
$$\sin(\alpha-90^\circ) = \cos\alpha$$
not $-\cos\alpha$

The only way to make this work is by taking the absolute value of $\beta$, but how is that logical if we are dealing with $-90^\circ$?

Thanks!

Comment: You have in the second term $\cos\alpha\sin 90$, not $\cos\alpha\sin(-90)$

Comment: So do I take the absolute value 90 instead of -90 simply because angles are never negative?

Comment: When matching "$\alpha-\beta$" with "$\alpha-90^\circ$", we have $\beta = 90^\circ$. The value of $\beta$ is whatever's being *subtracted* from $\alpha$; that's simply $90^\circ$. On the other hand, if you had wanted to use the formula $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, then you'd want to match "$\alpha+\beta$" with $\alpha-90^\circ$. Here, $\beta$ is something *added* to $\alpha$, so we reinterpret $\alpha-90^\circ$ as $\alpha+(^{-}90^\circ)$, so that $\beta = -90^\circ$.

Comment: @Pregunto: note at all: if `α – β = α – 90`, then `β  = 90`, that's all.

Comment: @Pregunto Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Write

$$\sin(\alpha - 90) = \sin\alpha\cos 90 - \sin 90\cos\alpha $$ $$= \sin \alpha \cdot 0 - 1\cdot\cos \alpha = -\cos \alpha.$$

Comment: So do I take the absolute value 90 instead of -90 simply because angles are never negative?

Comment: In the formula, the minus is not attached to the $90$.  See that $\beta$ travels by itself, leaving the minus behind.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, recall that by the [basic definitions and reflection properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections,_shifts,_and_periodicity)

$$\sin(\alpha-90^\circ)=-\sin(90°-\alpha)=-\cos \alpha$$